# not getting sms broadcast on xiomi redmi device

Tags: android, permissions, sms, broadcast, android-broadcast

I am working on a app which reads the otp code from incoming sms. I am using sms recieve broadcast to read the incoming sms. Its working fine on every device except xiomi redmi .
please help.

Comment: Where you able to get any solution on this one ? I'm too stuck at the same place

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for fetching activation code from sms inbox

Comment: Isuse seems to be resolved. Xiaomi has different permissions from what I have seen in other phones. This is what I had to do: go to settings, installed apps, find my test app, tap it, go to permissions manager and enable sms reading settings... i just enabled all . Then had to close app, clear cache (optional probably) and start it again. Event passed nicely this time. Problem resolved. –